# Why can I not delete "Python25" folder from my C disk?

Tags: python, uninstall

Why can I not delete "Python25" folder from my C disk? I have already uninstalled Python from the control panel, but I still can't get rid of this folder. Some message pops up (it's in Chinese so I don't quite understand, but I think it says something like I need to close some application and try again, but all applications are closed.)

It is Python 2.5.4.
I am using "Windows XP"

Has anyone here had a similar problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some process is still running with an open handle to the folder. (Just because you have no open application windows, it doesn't mean you have no running processes.)

Just reboot the system and try again.

If you really can't or don't want to reboot, use tools such as [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)  to detect what process is "using" the folder.

Comment: Thank You, Yes, I rebooted it and was able to deleted it then!

Answer (score 3):

This can also happen when you have a command prompt window open, and you are sitting in that directory.

Answer (score 2):

The Application [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/)  (Windows) allows you to right-click in a file/folder and see which processes are using that file. Once you know, it allows you to unlock said files and folders without needing to restart your computer.

I find it more straightforward that Process Explorer

Comment: ...and I find rebooting more straightforward than Unlocker :)

Answer (score 1):

If [rebooting](https://superuser.com/questions/186087/why-can-i-not-delete-python25-folder-from-my-c-disk/186088#186088) doesn't help, you could try [SysInternals MoveFile](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897556.aspx) to schedule it's deletion on the next reboot.

But in this case *something* is using the files and doing this might cause issues.